# change event not triggered with blur() method

Tags: javascript, html

When a user types something in an `<input type="text">` and removes the focus, both `blur` and `change` are fired.
However, when I do the same thing in JavaScript using the `blur()` method, only the `blur` event is fired and not the `change` event. Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

See this example code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq0uo1t5/)):

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Test</button>
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")

input.addEventListener("blur", () => console.log("blur"))
input.addEventListener("change", () => console.log("change"))

const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        input.focus()
    
        input.value = "something"
    
        input.blur()
    }, 1000)
})
```

When clicking the button, after a second, it should focus the input, change the value and blur the input. However, only the `blur` event is fired. Doing the same by hand will fire both events.

I like to trigger some validation logic on the `change` event and it works perfectly fine in real-live but when I try to recreate the workflow in a unittest it fails and I'm not sure why and how to solve it.
So the alternative question is: How can I trigger the `change` event from JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This issue

The `change` event is specifically emitted when a **user** interacts with an element. This is built in a was intentional. @see [HTMLElement: change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

### The solution

Use **[synthetic events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)** to mimic user interaction in changing the value: `input.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));`

Below is a working example with the logic in its own function `updateValueWithChangeEvent` .

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")

input.addEventListener("blur", () => console.log("blur"))
input.addEventListener("change", () => console.log("change"))

// Updates the value of an input and triggers the change Event.
const updateValueWithChangeEvent = (input, value) => {
  if (input.value === value) return
  
  input.value = value
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}

// Updated example using function above
const button = document.querySelector("button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // This will update value and trigger change event
        updateValueWithChangeEvent(input, "something")
        
        // This will trigger the blur event
        input.focus()
        input.blur()
    }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger an event like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const event = new Event("change");

// blur the input
input.blur();

// dispatch change event manually
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events